# Django not creating user after extending AbstractUser

Tags: django, django-forms

I tried extending my AbstractUser to allow more user types and to also allow users to create an account using their email address. However, I have been facing issues with user creation form on the frontend despite the fact that my Django admin works perfectly as I can create or sign in using email address instead of a username.

In addition, I noticed that anytime I submit the account creation form, the values auto-populate my browser's address bar, and of course, the user won't be created. I don't know if I can get some help to this issue, maybe I am simply missing a very vital step.

Below is a sample of auto-populated values shown in my browser's address bar when I (users) submit the form

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/company/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=7AC4rKoyFsYTkcOKLpaiREAYZQwu1i3hGlF51I3Svs65Kf4Fkc64j25YZAN2pKE4&email=jyak%40yahoo.com&password1=oluwasegun01&password2=oluwasegun01&name=Hedge&number_of_employees=20&country=1&phone=012345678901
```

Below are my codes:

> Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin, AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from accounts.managers import CustomUserManager
from accounts.validators import validate_digit_length
from data.models import Country


class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    #some other user types

    username = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('startup name'), max_length=250, blank=True)
    number_of_employees = models.IntegerField(_('no of employees'), blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone number'), max_length=11, validators=[validate_digit_length],
                             default='08012345678')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

> forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import transaction
from django.forms import EmailInput, TextInput

from data.models import Country
from .models import User, Company


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)


class CompanySignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'official company email'}))
    name = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'company name'}))
    number_of_employees = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'number of employees'}))
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'contact number'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm password',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'confirm password'}))
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'name', 'number_of_employees', 'country', 'phone', )

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Email already exists.")
        return email

    def save(self, commit=True):
        company = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

> Views.py

```
def company_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompanySignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'accounts/templates/signup_success.html')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Account creation failed. Please check for possible errors')
    else:
        form = CompanySignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/templates/company_signup.html', context={
        'title': _('Create Account'),
        'form': form,
    })
```

Comment: You don't have `method="post"` as an HTML attribute of your `<form>` tag in your template. I know this because you said " I noticed that anytime I submit the account creation form, the values auto-populate my browser's address bar".

Comment: OMG, thank you so much @Melvyn. That was quite a miss from me. You are absolutely spot on.